# jquery contains "all" words specified

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery contains to achieve some filtering functionality.

I have a table with 3 columns that contain some words

```
<table>
<thead>
<td>col1</td>
<td>col2</td>
<td>col3</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>z</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>e</td><td>b</td></tr>
<tr><td>o</td><td>f</td><td>b</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to call a function showme( string ) that will show me all the rows where string is found.
string can be 2 words

example if I call showme("a b"), I would get

```
<table>
<thead>
<td>col1</td>
<td>col2</td>
<td>col3</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>z</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>e</td><td>b</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would not get

```
<tr><td>o</td><td>f</td><td>b</td></tr>
```

because a is not in it, only b.

I tried using contains by chaining it but could not get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be easy, `$('tr:contains(a), tr:contains(b)')`

Comment: is that a AND ? will that return true only if both are found ?

Comment: Nope, if it contains any, do you want only elements that contains both ?

Comment: yes only those that contain both

Comment: That's even easier `$('tr:contains(a):contains(b)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the row that contains both letters you can do

```
$('tr:contains(a):contains(b)')
```

you can even chain on more `:contains` to the first TR if you need to

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for exact match you could use the `filter` method:

```
function showme(params) {
   params = params.split(' ');
   $('tbody tr').hide().filter(function() {
        return $(this.cells).filter(function() {
            return params.indexOf($.trim(this.textContent)) !== -1;
        }).length === params.length;
   }).show(); 
}

showme('a b');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/912dmaum/

If you want to pass several arguments to the function and not a space-separated string, you can use the `arguments` object:

```
function showme() {
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // ... 
}

showme('a', 'b', 'f');
```